# Am I supposed to re-check luggage at YYZ on a flight from Europe to USA?

Tags: transit, luggage, lost-luggage

I traveled in June this year from Germany to US through Toronto (AC flight). I did not have to re-check my luggage (in fact this is why I did chose this flight). Yesterday, I flew again, but this time my luggage is still Toronto - I was told by the employee at the US airport that I should have re-checked my luggage.

Were there some recent changes in the policy?

Update: My luggage was delivered two days later, unopened.

Comment: As far as I can tell, both Air Canada and YYZ agree that connecting to a US-bound flight in Terminal 1 (where Air Canada operates out of) should not need you to pick up your luggage in YYZ. Assuming both flights were in fact in T1, the only thing I can think of (besides handling error) is that your check-in agent in Germany only tagged your bags through to Toronto for some reason.

Comment: Who was your flight with this time? Was it two separate tickets, or same booking?

Comment: Single booking through United. AC flight.

Comment: Is it possible that last year, you went through US customs in the US, but this time you did that already in Toronto? This may make a difference. Not sure if this could be the case on this particular connection, though...

Comment: From my experience, the times when my international flights originated in Canada, the luggage was forwarded to the connecting flight. However, when my destination was in Canada from international destinations, I had to pick up my luggage in Toronto and re-check in. This has been the case for last several years.

Comment: I seem to remember this being the procedure years ago before they changed transit procedures in Canada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be in violation of their stated policy. See https://www.aircanada.com/en/travelinfo/airport/images/yyz.pdf
which for "international to USA"  states

> "Please note that your bags will be automatically transferred to your
>   connecting flight."

Comment: Maybe just the employee at the airport was not aware of this process and my luggage got stuck at YYZ due to some process mistake. Thank you for the reference!